# Lose Android dependencies and Android private libraries after clone project

Tags: android, android-library

I'm clone my android project from bitbucket to eclipse, but the project losed the

`Android dependencies` and `Android private libraries`

Please help me to get back that libraries.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

if you are use external jar file then simply download and put it in libs folder of the project.

otherwise go to project menu->clean with build immediately option.

Comment: I have cleaned the project, but it couldn't see the references libraries? I still not work

Comment: go  to project property->android select appropriate android version then clean and build.

if you are use external jar file then simply download and put it in libs